# protractor how to close modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I'm new to protractor and I can't seem to get modal dialog working.

**This is my code:**
http://puu.sh/jspPk/f6f41a798e.png

**Snippet:**

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="visitorExportModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="visitorExportModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">  
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width:78vw">    
<div class="modal-content">      
<div class="modal-header">        
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
</button>
```

Can anyone give me insights on how to close this dialog?

Comment: This isn't the answer you want, but if you want a cheap work-around, you can just refresh the page - browser.get('yourDesiredUrl - generally the one on which the browser lands after the page close');

Answer (score 2):

Why all answers simulate click?

You can just `toggle` the state of it like so:

```
$('#visitorExportModal').modal('toggle');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('button[class="close"]').click();
```

or if you might have multiple such buttons:

```
$('#visitorExportModal button[class="close"]').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element(by.css(".close")).click();
```

or

```
element(by.type("button")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation is used for classes:

```
$('button.close').click();
$('#visitorExportModal button.close').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me was more easy to do

```
        await browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 4, y: 4}).click().perform();
```

This is just click outside the modal in order to close itself (in my case was an informative dialog that can be closed by click outside)